# Getting java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection in spring boot application

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot

Getting below exception while executing a procedure in Spring boot application.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retrieving database metadata; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:141) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.initializeMetaData(CallMetaDataContext.java:286) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:303) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:288) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:348) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:386) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:193) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getMetaData(PhysicalConnection.java:4508) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar!/:11.2.0.3.0]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getMetaData(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:331) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

I have provided following properties in DataSource.

```
dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
dataSource.setMinIdle(5);
dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(60000);
dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(300000);
dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
dataSource.setValidationInterval(60000);
dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
dataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60000);
```

The same connection pool I am using to execute some other procedures and its working fine. Please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785340/oracle-db-java-sql-sqlexception-closed-connection

Comment: I had already checked that question and provided all the properties suggested in solutions. But still getting this issue.

Comment: @shubhamjain Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this using Hikari connection pool.
Check this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-know-which-connection-pool-is-used/) for how to replace default Tomcat connection pool by Hikari connection pool.