# Spring Data JPA Closed Connection

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

There is a function which inserts a record in the database with status "Running" at the start then do some long processing and at the end it updates the status to "Success" or "failed".

I am getting an error in the end while updating the status as processing took a long time ( 4 hrs to upload data to third-party app).

```
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again
        SQL: update STATUS set status=?
        o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again
        ERROR [-,f292b6c9becb8716,f292b6c9becb8716,false] 13556 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute batch]
WARN [-,f292b6c9becb8716,f292b6c9becb8716,false] 13556 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-2 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@7fb2645b marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(17008)

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:1828)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:1953)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:377)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:100)
```

How I can handle this situation?

**Below is my code snippet:**

```
public void upload() {

            entity.setStatus("RUNNING");
            repository.save(entity);

            try {
                //Uploads data to thrid party;
                callingThridPartyApp();
                log.info("Upload successfull.");
                entity.setStatus("SUCCESS");
                repository.save(entity);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Upload failed.", e);
                entity.setStatus("FAILED");
                repository.save(entity);
            } 

    }
```

Comment: Are you using connection pool?

Comment: alter the profile with the `IDLE_TIME` set to a higher value or `UNLIMITED`. https://dbaclass.com/article/ora-02396-exceeded-maximum-idle-time-please-connect/

Comment: Is there a way I can refresh the connection and perform the transaction again ? Because I cant set the IDLE_TIME for this application.

Comment: Try to use @Transactional annotation on top of your method.

Comment: @Thirumaran would it reset the connection? I am using Hikari database pool?

Comment: can you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785340/oracle-db-java-sql-sqlexception-closed-connection

Comment: Actually @Transactional annotation is from spring, It will takes care of entire DB connection flow.

Comment: @ChandreshMishra this request  callingThridPartyApp(); is taking too long. Can you somehow reduce it or find better way to update entity once this is completed?

Comment: @Lemmy I have used multithreading to call the third-party App which upload to S3 but numbers of records are too high. So it is taking time to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by stating a new transaction at the end of the long process to update the status in database.

```
        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void updateStatus(Entity entity) {

                log.info("Upload successfull.");
                entity.setStatus("SUCCESS");
                repository.save(entity);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Upload failed.", e);
                entity.setStatus("FAILED");
                repository.save(entity);
            } 
         }
```